# Attempt at building scraper, no output occurring

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Is this due to me selecting the wrong class when parsing? I was trying to print out to see if there were any errors, and with no output, I am stuck. I am trying to get only the price from the webpage.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


RetailSource1 = "https://www.bestbuy.com/site/nintendo-switch-32gb-console-neon-red-neon-blue-joy-con/6364255.p?skuId=6364255#anchor=productVariations"
RetailSource2 = "https://www.gamestop.com/consoles-hardware/nintendo-switch/consoles/products/nintendo-switch-with-joy-con-controller/204620.html"
RetailSource3 = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07VGRJDFY?tag=hawk-future-20&linkCode=ogi&th=1&ascsubtag=tomsguide-us-3111411964870790000-20"

def get_data(RetailSource2):
    r = requests.get(RetailSource2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    return soup

def parse(soup):
    results = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "actual-price"})
    print(len(results))
    return

soup = get_data(RetailSource2)
parse(soup)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo when you give the parser to BeatifulSoup.

"html.paser" should be "html.parser"

Notice the "r".

Comment: Thank you. Even with the edit, however, there is no output.